# Looking at individual bits

Tags: assembly, mips

In MIPS Assembly, is it possible to extract only i-th and j-th bits of a string and then place these individual bits back into their original location.

Consider: **1100**

Extract: *2nd* and *3rd* bits and swap them to get result **1010**

Comment: Absolutely possible, think about how you would do this say in C then just implement that in ASM.  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @dwelch
Yes this was a homework assignment. I actually wrote the code in C first using an array of chars. However, since i'm very knew to MIPS, I had trouble getting the offsets to work out and then the words I was getting were 8 bits.

Comment: In C one way is a = ((a&2)<<1)|((a&4)>>1)|(a&(~6));

Comment: and then convert that to asm, gusbro did an efficient variation on that, but should have let you do your own homework.

Comment: @dwelch
Thank you for your response. I remember seeing the exact same C statement in my textbook. Yes, _gusbro_ helped me out "too" much. Actually, I remember doing bit shifting for another assignment but had forgotten. Truthfully, it is not sinking in why bit shifting can be useful and how it can be utilized to extract bits.

Comment: the bit shifting is not part of the extracting bits necessarily the AND operation isolates the bit in question in that bit position.  you said you wanted to switch the bits so that means moving them in some form, shifting is an easy way to move bits, that is what shifting means.  ANDing or ORing is how you put a bit in its new location. To OR the bit in there the location needs to have a zero, to AND the bit in there the location needs to have a one.  (look at your OR and AND truth tables).

Comment: @dwelch
Ahhh man, you just saved me a ton of time and made my code 100x more efficient. Your second-to-last sentence is gold. The way I have been trying to incorporate for last hour or so is shifting each bit and then building new word. I can easily just do AND/OR like you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: see my very long answer I added below.  Hope this helps and was not too elementary...Then, please, go pass it on and surf around this website or some other and help someone out with something you know really well and they dont...

Comment: @dwelch
Thank you for your extended explanation. Really helped me out! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the AND truth table result r = a AND b

```
ab r
00 0
01 0
10 0
11 1
```

Look at these two cases:

```
10 0
11 1
```

anything ANDed with 1 is itself, now these two cases

```
00 0
01 0
```

anything ANDed with zero is zero.

with four bits abcd to extract the c bit, knowing these two features of anding, anything anded with zero and anything anded with one.

```
    abcd
AND 0010
=========
    00c0
```

we have isolated bit c and we dont care if it is a zero or a one bit we have isolated it.
the bits anded with zeros were forced to zero and the bit anded with a 1 was unchanged.

Likewise anding abcd with 0100 gives us 0b00 isolating bit b.

so now we have two intermediate results 0b00 and 00c0.  you wanted to swap their positions, shifting will do that, depending on your instruction set (I know you said mips but just follow please) some instruction sets might rotate or shift in the carry bit and some rotate or shift in zeros or arithmetic shifts vs logic shifts may duplicate the most significant bit instead of shift in zeros.  So you need to examine what shifting is available in the instruction set you are using and if there isnt a clean shifts in zeros solution then you need to add more operations to clean up any side effects of the shift.  In this case we want to move the b bit over one to the right and the c bit over one to the left so the operation you need to find and use is

```
0b00 >> 1 = 00b0
00c0 << 1 = 0c00
```

now the bits are in the right bit position we have three things

```
abcd
0c00
00b0
```

So we have two truth tables to examine, one is the AND truth table above and we know the anything anded with one, anything anded with zero thing.  the other is the OR truth table

```
ab r
00 0
01 1
10 1
11 1
```

In particular the first two

```
00 0
01 1
```

anything ORed with zero is itself.  and note the second two

```
10 1
11 1
```

anything ORed with 1 is 1.

How do we use AND and OR to get the bits in place?  Well we have two choices  anything ORed with zero is itself, the other is anything ANDed with 1 is itself.  what we need to do is manipulate the original number abcd and make it either a00d or a11d.  That calls into play the other half of the AND and OR tables. Anything anded with 0 is 0, anything orred with 1 is 1.  so to turn abcd into a00d we need to and it with 1001

```
    abcd
AND 1001
=========
    a00d
```

the a and d anded with one are themselves the b and c anded with 0 are 0

the other choice is

```
    abcd
OR  0110
=========
    a11d
```

a  and d are ored with 0 so they dont change b and c are orred with 1 so those bit locations become ones

the final step is to take our other intermediate values and mix them in

```
    a00d
OR  0c00
=========  
    ac0d

    ac0d
OR  00b0
=========  
    acbd
```

the other choice is more complicated, if we simply did this

```
    a11d
AND 0c00
========
    0c00
```

in order to use that identity we would need to modify the 0c00 and make it 1c11

```
0c00 OR 1011 = 1c11
1c11 AND a11d = ac1d
00b0 OR 1101 = 11b1
11b1 AND ac1d = acbd
```

In short the conventional solution is to and with ones to isolate, and with zeros to clean out the bit positions and then or in the new values:

```
abcd AND 0100 = 0b00
abcd AND 0010 = 00c0
0b00 >> 1 = 00b0
00c0 << 1 = 0c00
abcd AND 1001 = a00d
a00d OR 0c00 = ac0d
ac0d OR 00b0 = acbd
```

In C this would be something like this (and this shows your temporary variables)

```
//abcd is our original variable
tempb = abcd & 4;
tempc = abcd & 2;
tempb = tempb >> 1;
tempc = tempc << 1;
result = abcd & 9; 
result = result | tempc;
result = result | tempb;
//and finished, result contains the...result.
```

You already got a complete answer from gusbro, this is half the answer, I assume the task of using the logical operations is half the problem, the other half of the problem is choosing instructions and registers for the instruction set in question (notice how I have solved the problem thus far without needing to specify an instruction set, because at this point we can use any instruction set, it might take more than one instruction per step, but it is generic to this point).

Note this is a four bit solution, you are likely going to be using an instruction set with more than four bits in the registers so you need to know what bits to tack on the left of the operands in these equations to not mess up the other bits.

Another identity that gusbro used which I didnt, is anything XORed with itself is zero.  his two xor operations could be implemented with a single and operation with a constant, depending on the instruction set that might take more than one instruction or have additional memory cycles required.

the key to this type of work is understanding these logical identities and applying them.  when someone says (mask and shift) mask means anding with a constant that has ones in the bit positions you want to keep, then shifting puts the bit in a particular position, say for example you wanted to take abcd and isolate the c bit in such a way that the result is either a zero or one you would "mask and shift"

```
abcd AND 0010 = 00c0
00c0 >> 1 = 000c
```

The and is the mask, the shift is the shift, the result is a 0 if c was a 0 and 1 if c was a 1.

Likewise you can

```
abcd >> 1 = 0abc
0abc AND 0001 = 000c
```

shift then mask.

Your homework assignment could be re-arranged as

```
abcd >> 1 = 0abc
abcd << 1 = bcd0
0abc AND 0010 = 00b0
bcd0 AND 0100 = 0c00
abcd AND 1001 = a00d
00b0 OR 0c00 = 0cb0
a00d OR 0cb0 = acbd
```

and you can start to see other variations on the theme. and those variations can turn into optimizations depending on the instruction set you are targeting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by applying masks and shifts.
Assuming your data is stored in a register, to obtain the i-th bit you would apply an AND with the constant 2^i to clear all the bits but the i-th bit.
Then you can easily "move" that bit to other position using either a left shift or a right shift.

Now, to swap 2 bits would need a little more fiddling. You might for example,  extract the two bits to some registers, clear thos bits from the original register, then shift each of the two registers to locate them in the "swapped" position and finally OR everything.

E.g.:

```
  li $t0, 12         # Our constant, 1100b, is stored in $t0
  andi $t1, $t0, 2   # Mask the second bit and put it in $t1
  andi $t2, $t0, 4   # Mask the third bit and put it in $t2
  xor $t0, $t0, $t1  # Ensures the second bit $t0 is zero 
  xor $t0, $t0, $t2  # Ensures the third bit $t0 is zero 
  sll $t1, $t1, 1    # Moves $t1 one position to the left (second bit goes to third bit)
  srl $t2, $t2, 1    # Moves $t2 one position to the right (third bit goes to second bit)
  or $t1, $t1, $t2   # now we OR everything
  or $t0, $t0, $t1   # to get the final result, in this case 1010b
```

Comment: I now see how I can implement my solution. I had been struggling with this for hours!!! Thank you!